# SSO Request.IsAuthenticated is always false after the first Login, however the first SSO login works fine

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, request, single-sign-on

Please forgive me if upfront if I missed something or made a mistake.  I think I've only had to post here a couple of times....

I have googled this situation for two days trying this and that and am no closer to having this solved.  Something in Chrome changed and it broke my app.   The scenario is I have an MVC 5 app that uses SSO.   The first login brings me to the microsoftonline login page, and I can login successfully - upon which I am brought to my application redirectURI page and Request.IsAuthenticated = true.   All is good.   However, if I either close the browser or use the Log Out link (which executes the Logout code below) and try to access my app again, I am brought to microsoftonline login page as expected, enter my password, but the 2nd time Request.IsAuthenticated = false and my app no longer works.  It expects that Request.IsAuthenticated will be true, and because it is false it redirects back to microsoftonline's login page again resulting in a constant loop.   I have found that I can restart the web site and it somehow resets the Request.IsAuthenticated so I can login again.

I have no more ideas how to fix this.   Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the SSOAuthConfig:  (it's basically a carbon copy of the Azure App Registration ASP.Net Quick Start example)

```
internal static class SSOAuthConfig2020
{

    // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
    static string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

    // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in.
   static string  redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

    // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
    static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

    // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Microsoft identity platform endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0)
    static string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        var cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            CookieName = "MyFakeCookieName",
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
            SlidingExpiration = true,
        };
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
            // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
            // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter 
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true
            },
            // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60);
                    n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
                    n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
                    n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
                }
            }
        }
    );
    }
```

Here is the Login logic:

```
  public void SignIn()
    {
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Client" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
```

Here is the Log Out:

```
    public void SignOut()
    {
        try
        {

            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                 OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                 CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to my own question several months after asking it.   I posted the answer to help this person and am just linking to it to avoid duplication:

[Getting NULL Identity while authenticating user via Azure AD authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428993/getting-null-identity-while-authenticating-user-via-azure-ad-authentication)