# Azure Ad SSO successful received IdToken but Request.IsAuthenticated is false and claims null in asp.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to implement Azure AD SSO in asp.net MVC 5 application with OWIN middleware.
I have followed Microsoft article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp

After going through all this, I am successfully authenticated and redirected back to the application. I can see `IDToken` in the query string after successfull SSO process.

But the problem is `Request.IsAuthenticated` is always false and also `Claims` are null.

This is new project created just for the demo. I have gone through most of stack overflow questions related to this issue but none of those is working and i think it might be because of OWN nuget package version.

Here is my code :

Startup.cs :

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ServerSide_SSO.Startup))]

namespace ServerSide_SSO
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD. 
        string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];


        // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in. 
        string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

        // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant) 
        static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

        // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Microsoft identity platform endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0) 
        string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);



        /// <summary> 
        /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect  
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="app"></param> 
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            //app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()); 
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
            });
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config 
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page 
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                // ResponseType is set to request the code id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user 
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application 
                // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name 
                // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter 
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false, // This is a simplification 
                    NameClaimType = "name"
                },
                // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method 
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Redirecting to identity provider for sign in..");

                        context.ProtocolMessage.EnableTelemetryParameters = false;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseMode = null;

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },

                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = context => 
                    {

                        Debug.WriteLine("Authorization code received..");

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },

                    SecurityTokenReceived = context =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Token response received..");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },

                    SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Token validated..");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    TokenResponseReceived = context =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Token response received..");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    MessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Message received..");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }

                }
            }
        );
        }
        

        /// <summary> 
        /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="context"></param> 
        /// <returns></returns> 
        private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
            return Task.FromResult(0);

        }

        
    }
}
```

packages.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="3.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.11" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>
```

web.config has no authentication mode set

sign in method

```
 public void SignIn()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
            //return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

claims controller method

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var userAuthenticated = Request.IsAuthenticated;

            var userClaims = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;

            //You get the user's first and last name below:
            ViewBag.Name = userClaims?.FindFirst("name")?.Value;

            // The 'preferred_username' claim can be used for showing the username
            ViewBag.Username = userClaims?.FindFirst("preferred_username")?.Value;

            // The subject/ NameIdentifier claim can be used to uniquely identify the user across the web
            ViewBag.Subject = userClaims?.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

            // TenantId is the unique Tenant Id - which represents an organization in Azure AD
            ViewBag.TenantId = userClaims?.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid")?.Value;

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to setup an repro in my local But unable to get the same issue followed by this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp#register-your-application) the code you are using seems like correct, i tried with following OWIN middleware `NuGet packages` for my MVC Application (Version .Net 4.6.1):

Run From PowerShell :

```
 Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
    Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
    Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

[image]

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect" version="4.2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Please refer the below links for more information:

. [Microsoft AAD Identity And Access Management With MVC 5 Web Application.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/windows-azure-active-directory-identity-and-access-management-with-mvc-5-web-app/) .

.[Getting NULL Identity while authenticating user via Azure AD authentication| SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428993/getting-null-identity-while-authenticating-user-via-azure-ad-authentication)

.[Request.IsAuthenticated is false after logging into Active Directory| MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82bb5edb-cca6-4ad7-9ec6-b3f788048584/requestisauthenticated-is-false-after-logging-into-active-directory?forum=WindowsAzureAD) .